# MySQL How to count multiple entries while maintaining unique fileds

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables that look like this:

**acc_prop**

```
id | pid | uid
1  | 10  | 1
2  | 11  | 1
3  | 12  | 1
```

**cal**

```
id | pid
1  | 10
2  | 11
3  | 12
```

**price**

```
cid | rate
1   | 100
2   | 99
3   | 130
```

I want to create a query that returns a pid, a count of uid's with the same uid, and the rate for that pid.

**expected result**

```
pid  | uid_count | rate
10   | 3         | 100
11   | 3         | 99
12   | 3         | 130
```

my query looks like this

```
SELECT 
    cal.pid,
    count(ap3.uid) as uid_count,
    price.rate 
 FROM
    price 
 JOIN 
    cal on cal.id = price.cid
 JOIN
    acc_prop ap using(pid)
 JOIN
    acc_prop ap2 on ap2.uid = ap.uid
 JOIN
    acc_prop ap3 on ap3.uid = ap2.uid
 group by  ap3.pid;
```

But it returns

- the incorrect count
- the incorrect pid list
- the incorrect rate

**actual result**

```
pid  | uid_count | rate
10   | 9         | 100
10   | 9         | 100
```

Comment: Do we need `cal` at all here? Unfortunately the table names and foreign key names aren't particularly intuitive, so its hard to visualize the joins.

Comment: Not really, this is just a basic cutdown for the example. But in my real system, there is a cal table that links a pid with other tables. Basically cal is calendar, pid is propertyId and uid is userId. acc_prop is a table that links userId's with PropertyId's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after is this, viz to pre-calculate the number of users in `acc_prop` as a derived table, which you can then join through to the rest of the query:

```
SELECT 
    cal.pid,
    UserCount.Cnt,
    price.rate 
 FROM
    price 
    JOIN cal on cal.id = price.cid
    JOIN acc_prop ap using(pid)
 JOIN
 (
   SELECT uid, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
   FROM acc_prop
   GROUP BY uid
) UserCount
ON ap.uid = UserCount.uid;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a98bd/3)

Comment: Thats got it working, Thanks StuartLC. Im not very good with sub selects, hopefully this example will give me some hints in the future too.

Comment: The query joined to aliased as `UserCount` is called a `derived table` - these are really useful for breaking down larger problems into smaller chunks. Most other RDBMS (unfortunately not MySql yet) have `Common Table Expressions` which can be used for similar scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I think cal is not needed here, do you tried this:

```
SELECT 
    acc_prop.pid, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM acc_prop WHERE uid = uid) AS uid_count, price.rate
FROM 
acc_prop 
INNER JOIN price
ON acc_prop.id = price.cid
```